# How to get size of remote file?

Tags: python, paramiko

How to get size of remote file after upload file, using sftp paramiko client ? ?

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect( 'hostname', username = 'test', password = 'test', timeout=10)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
res = sftp.put(filepath, destination )
```

?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`.stat()` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.stat):

```
info = sftp.stat(destination)
print(info.st_size)
```

The `.stat()` method follows symlinks; if that is not desirable, use the [`.lstat()` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.lstat) instead.

See the [`SFTPAttributes` class information](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_attr.SFTPAttributes) for what attributes are available. `.st_size` is the size in bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method:

```
lstat(self, path)
```

See paramiko [docs](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.lstat)