# checking file size in a remote server using python, SSH

Tags: python, ssh

someone please help!

im currently writting a python script to actually retrieve a file size that is in a local PC and a remote server. then, what i do is, i compare if the file's size are the same. below is my code :

```
A = "/path/of/the/file/in/my/local/PC"
B = "/path/of/the/file/in/remote/PC"

statinfo1 = os.stat(A)
statinfo2 = os.system ("ssh" " root@192.168.10.1" " stat -c%s "+B)

if statinfo1 == statinfo2 :
   print 'awesome'
else :
   break
```

problem encountered : statinfo1 is able to return the file size in the local PC, but statinfo2 is not able to return the file size.. anyone please help? i want to use SSH method

Comment: does the `ssh` have password? If it does the above would not work.

Comment: You have `%s` but then you use `+`; its not doing what you think its doing.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid in this case `%s` is not meant for Python, but for the `stat` command (it means "show the total size in bytes")

Comment: Oh I see; however seeing the multiple `" "` in the string doesn't give me much confidence :)

Comment: You'll need to use `stat -c%s` on the local file aswell..

Answer (score 3):

Using paramiko or pexpect will work, but may be kind of heavyweight for your simple use case here.

You can use a lightweight solution that simply relies on `ssh` of the underlying OS, and python builtin `subprocess` module.

```
import os
A = "/path/of/the/file/in/my/local/PC"
B = "/path/of/the/file/in/remote/PC"

# I assume you have stat visible in PATH on both the local and remote machine,
# and that you have no password nags for ssh because you've setup the key pairs 
# already (using, for example, ssh-copy-id)

statinfo1 = subprocess.check_output('stat -c%s "{}"'.format(A), shell=True)
statinfo2 = subprocess.check_output('ssh root@192.168.10.1 stat -c%s "{}"'.format(B), shell=True)
```

Comment: Note: to do it without `shell=True`, which is not usually required, you will need to use the absolute path of stat (find with `which stat`) and split the command into an args list (using `shlex.split`)

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use [Paramiko SSHClient](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko). Its a nifty third party library simplifying `ssh` access.

So to check file size of remote file the code would be something like -

```
import paramiko, base64

B = "/path/of/the/file/in/remote/PC"

key    = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.decodestring('AAA...'))
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.get_host_keys().add('ssh.example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)
client.connect('192.168.10.1', username='root', password='yourpassword')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("stat -c " + B)
for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
client.close()
```

Check this too - [How to get size of remote file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834442/how-to-get-size-of-remote-file) and [SSH programming with Paramiko](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different)

Comment: all, i appriciate your help! below code helped me to solve my prob, posted by Brian Cain :                                              statinfo1 = os.stat(A).st_size
cmd = "ssh" " root@192.168.10.1" " stat -c%s "+B
rc, remote_stat = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)

if rc != 0:
   raise Exception('remote stat failure: ' + remote_stat)

statinfo2 = int(remote_stat)

if statinfo1 == statinfo2 :
   print 'awesome'
else :
   break

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at [fabric](http://fabfile.org) for easy remote tasks.

fabfile.py:

```
1 from fabric.api import run, env
2
3 env.hosts = ['user@host.com']
4
5 def get_size(remote_filename):
6     output = run('stat -c \'%s\' {0}'.format(remote_filename))
7     print 'size={0}'.format(output)
```

Shell command:

```
~ $ fab get_size:"~/.bashrc"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
statinfo1 = os.stat(A)
statinfo2 = os.system ("ssh" " root@192.168.10.1" " stat -c%s "+B)
```

### [What does `os.stat` return](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)?

- a data structure with several fields, one of which is the size.

### [what does `os.system` return](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)?

- it returns an `int` representing the exit code of the program invoked.

So the comparison between them is bound to fail.  Consider Paramiko as @Srikar suggests, or address the issues with this approach.

For the latter, try this:

```
import commands

statinfo1 = os.stat(A).st_size
cmd = "ssh" " root@192.168.10.1" " stat -c%s "+B
rc, remote_stat = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)

if rc != 0:
   raise Exception('remote stat failure: ' + remote_stat)

statinfo2 = int(remote_stat)

if statinfo1 == statinfo2 :
   print 'awesome'
else :
   break
```

Comment: Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3. Use the subprocess module instead.

Comment: i would really appriciate if someone could help me to understand whatis:                                                              rc, remote_stat and what does 'if rc != 0' means

Comment: @Noob, if you're satisfied with these answer(s), please select one as the official answer to your question.

Comment: @wim, indeed, `subprocess` is a better alternative.

Comment: sure Brian and Win. both your solutions worked fine for me. i appriciate alot! thanks again